# error Invalid type "boolean | undefined" of template literal expression @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions

Tags: typescript, boolean, typescript-eslint

When using eslint's **"restrict template expressions"**, how do you log a `boolean` variable?  Also, if I wanted to disable the restriction for a line, how to do it?

```
const flag:boolean = true;

console.log("flag=" + flag);
console.log(`flag=${flag}`);
```

both generate this error:

`error  Invalid type "boolean | undefined" of template literal expression  @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `.eslintrc`:

```
module.exports = {
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions": "error"
  }
};
```

Ref: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/restrict-template-expressions/

You can suppress the error for a line like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
console.log(`flag=${flag}`);
```

Just a little suggestion, if you are using typescript, maybe you should use `const` or `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly type cast to `string`, like so:

```
const flag:boolean = true;

console.log(`flag=${flag as string}`);
```